# How can I prevent passing in type parameters everywhere when using Generic Polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a couple of classes that inherit from a base class. It is basically a Result returned by a method that contains a Status object.

```
public abstract class ResultBase<TResult, TStatus>
    where TResult : ResultBase<TResult, TStatus>
    where TStatus : ResultStatusBase<TStatus>, new()
{   
    protected ResultBase(TStatus status)
    {
        this.Status = status;
    }

    public TStatus Status { get; internal set; }

    public static TResult ServerUnavailable(string message = "") => _getResult(0, message);

    public static TResult Ok(string message = "") => _getResult(1, message);

    protected static TResult GetResult(int statusValue, string message)
    {
        var status = Enumeration.FromValue<TStatus>(statusValue);
        return (TResult)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TResult), status, message);
    }
}


public abstract class ResultStatusBase<T> : Enumeration
    where T : ResultStatusBase<T>, new()
{
    public ResultStatusBase(int value, string displayName)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    public int Value { get; protected set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    public static readonly T Ok = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 0, "Ok") as T;

    public static readonly T ServerUnavailable = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 1, "Server Unavailable") as T;
}
```

These classes can be used to create concrete classes

```
public class CreateStatus : ResultStatusBase<CreateStatus> 
{
    public static readonly CreateStatus AlreadyExists = new CreateStatus(100, "Already exists");
}

public class CreateResult: ResultBase<CreateResult, CreateStatus>
{
    public static CreateResult AlreadyExists(string message = "") => GetResult(100, message);
    // Some stuff specific to a create result
}
```

So far, so good. I can create derived classes from `ResultBase` and ResultStatusBase`.

## The catch

These results and statuses are used all over the application. As an example I have an http client that returns a result.

In this http client I have to pass in both type parameters, use reflection to create an instance and get values and use strings to get the field names.

```
internal class MyHttpClient<TResult, TStatus>
    where TResult : ResultBase<TResult, TStatus>, new()
    where TStatus : ResultStatusBase<TStatus>, new()
{
    public static GetOkResult()
    {
        return this.GetResult(
            status: this._getStatusFieldValue("Ok"),
            message: "It's Ok");
    )

    public TResult GetResult(TStatus status, string message)
    {
        var result = new TResult();

        return new TResult
        {
            Status = status
        };
    }

    private TStatus _getStatusFieldValue(string fieldName) =>
        typeof(TStatus)
            .GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            ?.GetValue(null) as TStatus;
}
```

## The question

This is all starting to feel like a wart is growing in my application, but I don't know how to get passed this one. 
Can anyone help me with a better design?

Comment: Your question title and the question body are quite different. The title asks a simple yes or no question, but the body asks a much broader, less-well-defined "better design" question, which is likely to be closed as primarily opinion based due to there being to objective way of determining "better".

Comment: Im confused why does `ResultBase` have a `TResult` which is constraint to be of its own type? You dont seem to use that generic type at all in its implementation.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do?

Comment: `nameof(result.Status)` is a **compile-time** constant. So why do you even use all this reflection-stuff, if you know the types and members at compile-time? just use `var result = new TResult(); result.Status = status; result.Message = message`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your reply. I changed the question title.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm using reflection because `new()` cannot take any constructor parameters (as far as I know), and `Status` is an internal property. So since `MyHttpClient` is in another package I have to use reflection.

Comment: Can you use more generic interface(for ResultBase) without type parameters but object type and then inside the ResultBase cast it to the TResult?

Comment: There´s still a pointless `result.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(result.Status))`. The exact type is known at compile-time and thus that is has a `Status` (because `TResult` is a `BaseResult<>`). So you can further simplify this to `result.Status = status`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I changed it. But for this to happen I had to add `InternalsVisibleTo` to the project that contains `ResultStatus` and `ResultStatusBase`

Comment: @ViktorArsanov Could you give me an example of what `ResultStatus` would look like with your suggestion?

Comment: Okay, I see. Thought they were in the same assembly, as they both were `internal`.

Comment: Well, I think what you have now, var result = new TResult();return new TResult
        {            Status = status        }; is what you need. But my proposition was to introduce interfaces without type parameters like IResult, IStatus - it would help to separate properties where type not needed from the ones which require generic type parameter. And inside IResult you could have void SetResult(object) and inside implementation you would cast it to the type you need. But I think it doesn't make sense now since you have type information(TResult) and the code you have now is fine.